# Sensor stops working on Standby in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I registered my Service at the notification manager to prevent Android from shutting me down. 
I also registered a WakeLock with:

```
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager
            .newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, 
                    TAG);
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

The Sensor firing rate still goes down when the screen of the phone is shut off. Is there any way I can keep up the maximum firing rate even when the phone goes on standby mode?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some `WakeLock` to prevent device's CPU from shuttong down?